# Solr search returns different output

Tags: search, solr, lucene, arabic, bitnami

I am using bitnami solr 4.6.0-1 for seraching arabic and english word. While i am trying to search an arabic word say for example:'أبدل خبير' it brought 4 output as follows

```
<result name="response" numFound="4" start="0">
<doc><str name="Arname">أبدل</str></doc>
<doc><str name="Arname">أبدل يحيا</str></doc>
<doc><str name="Arname">كلسم حبير</str></doc></doc>
<doc><str name="Arname">حبير</str></doc>
```

Query executed like `select?q=Arname%3A++أبدل+خبير~0.75&fl=Arname&wt=xml&indent=true`

But when i searchd the word in reverse order 'خبير أبدل' it brought only 2 output

```
<result name="response" numFound="4" start="0">
<doc><str name="Arname">أبدل</str></doc>
<doc> <str name="Arname">أبدل يحيا</str></doc>
</result>
```

Query Executed like `select?q=Arname%3A++خبير+أبدل~0.75&fl=Arname&wt=xml&indent=true`

The field type set to Arname is text_ar
The Schema of text_ar is as follows

```
<fieldType name="text_ar" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <!-- for any non-arabic -->
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_ar.txt" />
            <!-- normalizes ﻯ to ﻱ, etc -->
            <filter class="solr.ArabicNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.ArabicStemFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Please tell me a solution for this.

Comment: numFound="4" and you get only two results, are you sure?

Comment: it will show 4 out put if number found ="4". But that is not my problem. If the searching word is searched in different order out put retrieved is different. Suppose say 'ABC EFG' is a Arabic word. Then if it is searched like 'EFG ABC' it shows different output.